# GLPK# integer programming

Tags: c#, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I need to write an integer program. It's incredibly simple, but the problem is there is next to no good information on how to write integer programs for GLPK using the callable library, let alone for GLPK#.

My integer program looks very much like this:

```
Maximise: X[0] + X[1] + ... + X[n];

s.t.      X[1] + X[5] <= 1;
          X[1] + X[7] <= 1;
          X[2] + X[4] <= 1;
          X[3] + X[9] <= 1;
          ...
          X[i] = {0,1}
```

I have a bunch of binary X's, and I want to maximise the sum. Certain X's preclude certain other X's.

All I've managed to do so far is

```
LPProblem lp = new LPProblem()
{
  ModelClass = MODELCLASS.MIP,
  ObjectiveDirection = OptimisationDirection.MAXIMISE,
  ObjectiveName = "Z"
};

// Stuff goes here, I'm not sure how to represent the model

SOLVERSTATUS status = lp.SolveInteger();
```

Comment: You are right, there seems to be hardly any documentation for this library. Perhaps it would be best just to see what is available in the source code...the most recent version is at http://yoyovicks.blog.free.fr/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could use something other than GLPK#. If you're an academic you can get CPLEX or Gurobi for free. Otherwise, Google OR Tools has had C# support for the past year. According to the [Google OR Tools page](https://code.google.com/p/or-tools/), it includes a wrapper for GLPK and CBC. Simply for the fact that you can switch between the two solvers, I'd recommend using Google OR Tools. You may find one solver better than the other for your particular instances.

Comment: To add to this, there are also some open source alternatives with C# interfaces, namely [LPSolve](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/) and [CoinMP](http://www.coin-or.org/download/source/CoinMP/). Both solvers have MIP support. They are primarily C/C++ codes, but both provide good C# interfaces through P/Invoke.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not completely up on SO etiquette. Should I edit my answer to include the solvers you suggested?

Comment: I do not think you need to, your answer is perfectly valid. I just thought I should mention some open-source alternatives to provide more options.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few other comments to fill this out a bit more. Firstly GLPK is OK, but is quite slow for large models - if you are facing a large problem (even if that is way in the future) you may be better off looking at some other solvers like those already mentioned. Also GLPK# development seems to be very quiet - I've not seen any updates for almost 2 years. That might be a good thing (it's stable and works, so why change it) or it might be that it is stalled.

As already mentioned, both Gurobi and CPLEX are really strong powerful fast solvers, and provide good modelling APIs in C#. If you can get access to those, they are really worth it. The SCIP solver is good - probably the best of the non-commercial solvers, but I am not sure about a C# interface.

Another potential advantage of the Google OR tools is the emphasis on constraint programming - if you have a complex set of binary variables and constraints, then the CP approach may have some advantages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you describe is called the "Maximum Clique Problem".  Create an undirected graph whose vertices are labeled 1 through n.  If you have a constraint of the form x[i] + x[j] <= 1 then draw an edge between i and j.  Let H be the complementary graph -- i.e. where you have an edge between i and j if and only if you *don't* have an edge between i and j in G.  A clique is a subset of vertices each of which is connected by an edge to all of the other members of S.  Your problem is to find a clique of maximum size.  This is a well-known NP-complete problem.  Nevertheless there are a number of pretty good heuristic algorithms (and probably even software available) to solve this.  Look at the following survey http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.17.5821

The IP formulation that you give is not very tight, and so, unless n is fairly small, even with top solvers such as CPLEX and GUROBI, you may not solve your problem in a reasonable amount of time with that formulation.